# How can I do this complex SQL query using Django ORM? (sub-query with a join)

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, gtfs

I'm used to writing my own SQL queries and I'm trying to get used to the whole ORM thing that seems to be so popular nowadays.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT * FROM routes WHERE route_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT t.route_id FROM stop_times AS st 
    LEFT JOIN trips AS t ON st.trip_id=t.trip_id
    WHERE stop_id = %s
)
```

where %s is an integer.

I'm using Django's default ORM. What's the most pythonic way to do this?

Some background info: The DB I'm using is from a GTFS (Google Transit feed specification). This query is supposed to get a list of every `route` that goes through a particular `stop`, however the info linking these is in the `trips` table.

This query works just fine for me, so the only reason I'm asking is to learn.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd probably be a bit easier to figure out the appropriate way to do this if you had what you were using for the relevant `Models`.

I'm assuming something like the following, based on the specification you mentioned working from:

```
class Route(models.Model):
    #bunch of stuff
    pass
class Stop(models.Model):
    #bunch of stuff
    stop_times = models.ManyToManyField(through=StopTime)
class StopTime(models.Model):
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip)
    stop = models.ForeignKey(Stop)
    # bunch of additional meta about this M2M table
    pass
class Trip(models.Model):
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route)
    # bunch of stuff
```

If that's the case... you should be able to do something like

```
Route.objects.filter(trip__stop__id=my_stop_id)
```

to get all `Route` objects that go through a given `Stop` with a primary key `id` equal to `my_stop_id`, which I'm assuming is an integer as per your post.

I apologize if the syntax is a bit off, as I haven't needed to do many-to-many relationships using an explicit extra table. Some adjustment may also be needed if you have to (or choose to) use the `related_name` parameter for any the foreign keys or the many-to-many-field.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is quite helpful. You got the models right and I will try this query soon.

One more question: What's the difference between a ForeignKey and a ManyToMany?

Comment: `ForeignKeys` are for many-to-one relationships, and put in the `Model` on the Many side. ManyToManyFields are for many-to-many relationships; it doesn't actually matter that much, internally which of the two related models it's put in, so you usually put it in the one where you're more likely to want to edit it (in, say the built in Django admin forms). A table is automatically made to represent the relation ship, which basically consists of two `ForeignKey` objects.

Comment: (oh, but in this case, since there's additional meta data about the many-to-many relationship, I instead assumed you'd be doing it manually, through `StopTime`. That's why the `through` parameter needed to be used for the `ManyToManyField`. If you decided the additional data given for `StopTime` was extraneous other than the many-to-many information, then you could eliminate the `StopTime` model and the `through` parameter. Normal Django naming conventions would then have you name the `ManyToManyField` as `times` or something similar, then.)

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you can do that with Django ORM in a normal way.

There is no subquery support and with a normal join it would depend on your database if a distinct could help you. If you are using Postgres than you could do it with this patch: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6422

The query would be something like this:

```
Route.objects.filter(stop_time__trips__stop_id=...).distinct('stop_time__route_id')
```